# backbone use existing model data without another call to the server

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and I thought one of the great things was that I could access the data without going back to the server. In the old version of my app, I was storing a hash of data in a dom node using jQuery.data.

So I have a list of messages, and when I click on a message, I want to go to a view which shows me more details, but all the details I need are already in the original list, so I don't actually need another run to the server, I just want to update the view.

Then when I want to go back to the list, again, I don't need to go back to the server, I just want to go back to the original list.

My routes look like this, and I tried to pass the 'messages' variable into the show function, but it isn't available to that function.

Am I misunderstanding the capabilities of backbone?

```
App.Routers.Messages = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "":             "index",
        "messages/:id":     "show"
    },

    show: function(id){
        var message = new Message({ id: id});
        message.fetch({
            success: function(model, resp){

                new App.Views.Show({ model: message});
            },
            error: function(){
                new Error({message: "Hey!? Were'd it go? sorry I can't find your message"});
                window.location.hash = '#';
            }
        });
    },

    index: function(){

        var messages = new App.Collections.Messages();
        message.fetch({
            success: function(){

                  new App.Views.Index(messages);

            },
            error: function(){
                new Error({ message: "did not find message :("});
            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you desire with Backbone as well.

The only change you have to make is to set the collection of models to a global accessible variable.

So in the index function replace

```
var messages = new App.Collections.Messages();
```

with

```
App.messages = new App.Collections.Messages();
```

And then in your show function replace

```
var message = new Message({ id: id});
```

with

```
var message = App.messages.get(id);
```

Comment: though I think you're close Paul, unfortunately, when I click on a message, I get an 'undefined' in the console.log for show App.messages.get(id). also, with the supplied code, when going back to a the messages view, I guess I would just check the length of messages, and if < 1, set-up the fetch?? For some reason i thought backbone took care of this sort of plumbing

Comment: It probably has to do with fetch retrieving the models from the server asynchronously

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the router works exactly like that: a route, once you click on the messages/:id view it reinitializes a *new* Messages model etc. If you move the fetch to the initialize method of your View and return that View as a so-called singleton (e.g. initialize it only once in your application), you won't need to do another server-call.

Comment: kinda getting what you're saying, but what about when I do need to make a server call?? I'm trying to just get back to the page I had before without another request, but there are times when I'll want to load new data.